# Which extant species has the largest horns?

Tags: zoology

Among the bovids (cattle, antelope and all member of the *Bovidae* family): which species has the largest and longest horns? Please answer when including and excluding domesticated livestock and cattle.

I know that the [Addax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addax) has about 85-110 cm long horns and they seem pretty long, but not as robust as a bull's horns. 
Wikipedia writes that [Greater Kudu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_kudu) has 120 cm long horns with a record of 187 cm (this figure, however, has a "citation needed" warning).
The extinct bovid [Pelorovis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelorovis) had 1 meter horn cores and covered with keratin their length is estimated at 200 cm. 
I saw in photos several (live) specimen of specially breaded cattle that had exceptionally big horns but I could not measure them.

For comparison, the longest *Triceratops* (an horned dinosaur) horns I know of are "Yoshi's Trike" 115 cm long horn cores with estimated total length of 130-150 cm when covered in keratin. However, the horns of *Triceratops* were thicker and more robust than any extant bovid's horns.

Comment: Why do you want to know something like this?

Comment: General interest. I am interested in numbers, records and records breakers.

Comment: Seems to me more Guinness Book of Records than biology, then, but who am I to judge.